# Neo4jrestclient error Unable to get root

Tags: python, neo4j

Earlier my code was working fine, suddenly while running my Python script:

```
**from neo4jrestclient.client import GraphDatabase
from bottle import route, run,template,post,request,redirect
gdb = GraphDatabase("http://localhost:7474/db/data/")*
@route('/home')
def open_home():
    username=""
    parties=[]
    return template('home',dict(username=username,parties=parties))
```

This error shows up:

> Traceback (most recent call last): > File "bottle3.py", line 4, in  > gdb = > GraphDatabase("localhost:7474/db/data/") File > "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/neo4jrestclient/client.py", > > line 78, in **init** > raise NotFoundError(response.status_code, "Unable get root") neo4jrestclient.exceptions.NotFoundError: Code > [411]: Length Required. > Client must specify Content-Length.. Unable > get root

Comment: i believe you are running the script by another user than before

Comment: Which versions of neo4jrestclient and Neo4j are you running?

Comment: version 2.1.3 for linux

Answer (score 3):

Have you removed all nodes in the database?

Have you upgraded to Neo4j >=2.0? With the [release of 2.0.0 RC1](http://neo4j.com/blog/neo4j-2-0-0-rc1-final-preparations/) the database no longer contains a default node 0 (reference node), previously known as root.

I can recommend [neo4jdb-python](https://github.com/jakewins/neo4jdb-python/) for an up to date python driver.

Comment: I Already tried adding nodes of the sample movie database given by then , last time i had this problem i had it fixed by inserting new nodes , but no luck this time .